# Android studio 3.0.1 switch on gps using broadcast receiver

Tags: android

Android studio 3.0.1

Is there a way to switch on gps using a broadcastreceiver?

Or service which doesn't need the user of pressing any button?

Cause I'm writing a app which when the user's screen is switch on, the gps turn on.

I've googled it but isn't working for me .

Comment: Turning on the GPS needs user interaction. If so, your service needs to brings up the page ask user to enable GPS ...

Comment: However this can bee done once in setup, asking user to give permission to access forever from settings

Comment: Aha..so theres no way of switching it on without users interaction?

Comment: It needs user interaction the very first time the app is run. Not after that.

Comment: Tnx alot. Arnt.